# How to insert a new tag with attribute inside xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file as follows in which i want to add one more tag with attributes inside it using a python script.

```
<package> 
  <data> 
    <id>sample</id> 
    <version>1.1</version> 
  </data>
  <files>
   <file src = "C:/sample.txt"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

The python script with which i am adding the tag with attribute is as follows script but its not adding the tag as i desire:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree_A = ET.parse('test.xml')
root_A= tree_A.getroot()
print root_A[1].tag
if root_A[1].tag is not None:    
    newNodeName = ET.Element('file src')
    newNodeName.text ="D:/other.txt"
    newNode.append(newNodeName)
    root_A[1].insert(0,newNodeName)
tree_A.write('test.xml')
```

and the output xml i am getting is:

```
<package> 
  <data> 
    <id>sample</id> 
    <version>1.1</version> 
  </data>
  <files>
   <file src = "C:/sample.txt"/>
   ###i want following tag as <file src ="D:/other.txt"/>
   <file src> D:/other.txt</file src> 
  </files>
</package>
```

So, please suggest how can i have a tag with attribute being added in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ET.Element('file', {'src':'D:/other.txt'})` to construct the element named `file` with an attribute named `src`.